# mpfr_free_cache in destructor - a good idea?

Tags: c++, multithreading, malloc, arbitrary-precision, mpfr

I need arbitrary precision in a C++ program, so I am using the well-known, lightweight C++-wrapper `MPFRC++` over the multi-precision floating point C-library `MPFR`.

I have been having memory issues.  Namely, a `malloc` fails within an MPFR function. (small piece of error message at bottom, if you are interested).

The MPFR manual says (page 10)

> MPFR functions may create caches, e.g., when computing constants such as pi, either because the user has called a function like mpfr_const_pi directly or because such a function was called internally by the MPFR library itself to compute some other function.
>
> At any time, the user can free the various caches with mpfr_free_cache. It is strongly advised to do that before terminating a thread...

My program is heavily multi-threaded, so I suppose I need to start using this `mpfr_free_cache`.

**Question:**
Can I simply place `mpfr_free_cache()` in the *destructor* for the wrapping class?  Is this safe and good practice?  Is it enough to solve the problem?(assuming I have correctly identified the memory leak)

e.g.

//  mpreal.cpp  -   implementation of wrapper

```
namespace mpfr {
class mpreal {
    mpreal::mpreal() 
    { 

        #if defined (MPREAL_HAVE_CUSTOM_MPFR_MALLOC)
            set_custom_malloc();
        #endif

        mpfr_init2(mp,default_prec); 
        mpfr_set_ui(mp,0,default_rnd);

        MPREAL_MSVC_DEBUGVIEW_CODE;
    }

    .......

    mpreal::~mpreal() 
    { 
        mpfr_clear(mp);
            mpfr_free_cache();    // ADD THIS TO DESTRUCTOR ?!?!
    }  

    ......
```

I am not a developer by trade, so I don't know if this is really the best way to solve the problem.  But I am not too excited about the idea of going into every OpenMP multi-threaded region/for-loop and squeezing in an `mpfr_free_cache()`...

Note:  I have built MPFR with the thread-safe option.

---

Here is that error message, if you are interested...

```
MPFR: Can't allocate memory (size=5864071192896)
[ccmb011:00985] *** Process received signal ***
[ccmb011:00985] Signal: Aborted (6)
[ccmb011:00985] Signal code:  (-6)
[ccmb011:00985] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x2b952b8cc7c0]
[ccmb011:00985] [ 1] /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x2b952bb09265]
[ccmb011:00985] [ 2] /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x110) [0x2b952bb0ad10]
[ccmb011:00985] [ 3] /users/mmparks/MPFR/lib/libmpfr.so.4(mpfr_default_reallocate+0) [0x2b9529abebd0]
[ccmb011:00985] [ 4] /users/mmparks/MPFR/lib/libmpfr.so.4(mpfr_tmp_allocate+0x2e) [0x2b9529abec6e]
[ccmb011:00985] [ 5] /users/mmparks/MPFR/lib/libmpfr.so.4(mpfr_mul+0x69d) [0x2b9529a9c5bd]
[ccmb011:00985] [ 6] /users/mmparks/MY_PROGRAM
```

code referenced in the error-message:

```
  ret = malloc (size);
  if (ret == NULL)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "MPFR: Can't allocate memory (size=%lu)\n",
               (unsigned long) size);
      abort ();
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that it appears you're trying to allocate 5.8TB of memory. Not very many systems out there that can satisfy that allocation request.... You'll need to look at where `size` comes from and how it got to be that big...

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and wasn't sure what to make of it -  that line appears within an MPFR function (for temporary calculations), so I don't have any control over it...

Comment: You may not control the code, but if you trace `size` back to where it was calculated, you *might* find that it's based on values you provided to MPFR in some way, or it might be an actual MPFR bug. Figuring out which would at least shed more light on the problem...

Comment: Agreed.  Unfortunately, valgrind makes the program unbelievable slow... so I can do the trace and let you know next week maybe :P

Comment: Actually.  I ran it with valgrind and found nothing (with both `--leak-check=full` and `--track-origins=yes`).  The program aborted and valgrind had nothing to say.

Comment: I just added some more of the error-message in the post...